# How to specify the path for require_once in a child theme?

Tags: php, theme-development, child-theme

I have a child theme folder called themes/child-theme and inside I have a file dashboard_payments.php.
Under the child theme folder I'm creating a new folder called gateway and inside there's a config.php.

So, how do I do a require_once inside dashboard_payments.php to call the file gateway/config.php? How would the require_once or include line look like?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 4.7 [`get_theme_file_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_path/) is the right function to use:

```
require_once get_theme_file_path( 'gateway/config.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
require_once(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/gateway/config.php');
```

or (should be faster)

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/gateway/config.php');
```